# Responsive layouting with mdbootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I'm using mdbootstrap4 to create a prototype UI for a web application.

I've been trying to achieve the following:

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcfd8.jpg)

Essentially, the login container scales up as screen width increases. As the available screen width decreases (on mobile), the link and button should conform to mobile UI patterns: login button first, full width of its container. I've been trying to get this to work, but either the link text overflows (multiple lines) or the button's dimensions become weird and overflows the text as well.

Additionally, I can't seem to fix the responsive ordering and alignment.

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center text-white">
            <!-- Headers -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="login-form" class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-10">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form name="">
                      <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
                        <label for="form1">E-mailadres</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="form2" class="form-control">
                        <label for="form2">Password</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="container mt-5">
                        <div class="row align-items-center text-right">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 order-first order-sm-last text-right">
                                <a href=".">Ik ben mijn paswoord vergeten</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block order-last order-sm-first" target=".">Inloggen</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been fiddling to find an elegant solution to this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center text-white"> 
            <!-- Headers --> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="login-form" class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-10">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form name="">
                        <div class="md-form"> <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
                            <label for="form1">E-mailadres</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="md-form"> <i class="fa fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="form2" class="form-control">
                            <label for="form2">Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container mt-5">
                            <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 order-last order-sm-last text-right"> <a href=".">Ik ben mijn paswoord vergeten</a> </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 order-md-last">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block order-last order-sm-firstt" target=".">Inloggen</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```